# how to map javascript dictionary keys to new keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary contains windows os versions,like:

```
{
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200": 1,
  "32-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9137": 2,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700": 3,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200": 4
}
```

and I have a map to map windows NT 6.* to windows 7 or windows 8, like:

```
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.*->windows 7
Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.*->windows 8
```

So how can I map the old dictionary to the new one with the format:

```
{
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows 8": 1,
  "32-bit Microsoft Windows 8": 2,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows 7": 7
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just iterate through the properties and map them to a new dictionary output, changing the values that you need for the keys.

Comment: Post also your code attempts please.

Comment: You can iterate through all the keys using a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and compare strings using [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: to create a new object empty, iterare throught object (map), modify keys using regex, store in new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `for..in` and `String.prototype.replace` on keys you could put together something like this

```
var old_dict = {
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200": 1,
  "32-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9137": 2,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700": 3,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200": 4
};

var new_dict = (function (d1) {
    var k1, k2, d2 = {},
        re = /NT (\d+\.\d+)\.\d+/,
        version_map = { // major.minor version number mappings
            '6.1': '7',
            '6.2': '8'
        };
    function replacer($0, $1) { // if we don't have a map, default to what was put in
        return version_map[$1] || $0;
    }
    for (k1 in d1) {
        k2 = k1.replace(re, replacer);
        d2[k2] = (d2[k2] || 0) + d1[k1]; // add together if already exists
    }
    return d2;
}(old_dict));

/* new_dict looks like {
    "64-bit Microsoft Windows 8": 1,
    "32-bit Microsoft Windows 8": 2,
    "64-bit Microsoft Windows 7": 7
} */
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be {64-bit Microsoft Windows 8: 1, 32-bit Microsoft Windows 8: 2, 64-bit Microsoft Windows 7: 4} ?

Comment: @ScottVickers see desired output in OP's question; `6.1.3700` (`3`) and `6.1.1200` (`4`) both map to Windows 7 and desired output is `7` (`= 3 + 4`)

Comment: Good point.  I just assumed the values were passed through.  Shouldn't have assumed, heh.

Comment: @ScottVickers well I'm doing some assuming here too because `3 | 4` is also `7`, but the chosen numbers don't look like bit flags because `3` is `1 | 2`, but these are already used for other entries.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use Regular Expressions to match your targets, as in:

```
var maps = {
// result => RegExp
  '64-bit Microsoft Windows 7': /64-bit.+?NT\s6\.1/,
  '32-bit Microsoft Windows 8': /32-bit.+?NT\s6\.2/,
  '64-bit Microsoft Windows 8': /64-bit.+?NT\s6\.2/
};

var test_data={
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200": 1,
  "32-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9137": 2,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700": 3,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200": 4
};

var result={};

for(key in test_data){
  for(target in maps){
    if(maps[target].test(key)){
      if(!result[target]){
        result[target]=0;
      }
      result[target]+=test_data[key];
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.dir(result);
```

which will produce:

```
{ '64-bit Microsoft Windows 8': 1,
  '32-bit Microsoft Windows 8': 2,
  '64-bit Microsoft Windows 7': 7 }
```

#### UPDATED

The regexes could be a little more precise, to expose possible outlying cases, by anchoring them to the start and end of the string, as in:

```
`/^64-bit.+?NT\s6\.1.+$/`
```

which can be described as:

```
^            # beginning of target string
64-bit       # literal '64-bit'
.+?          # one or more chars, non-greedy
NT           # literal 'NT'
\s           # literal space
6\.1         # literal '6.1'
.+           # one or more chars, greedy
$            # end of target string
```

You may also wish to report targets that **do not** match your target patterns by refactoring to:

```
for(key in test_data){
  var found=false;
  for(target in maps){
    if(maps[target].test(key)){
      if(!result[target]){
        result[target]=0;
      }
      result[target]+=test_data[key];
      found=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
    console.warn('encountered unknown record at key "%s"',key)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks. And it's robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the object and change them as necessary.

For example:

```
var myObj = {
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200": 1,
  "32-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9137": 2,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700": 3,
  "64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200": 4
};

var myNewObj = {
    "64-bit Microsoft Windows 7" : 0,
    "64-bit Microsoft Windows 8" : 0
};

for (var key in myObj){
    if (key.indexOf("Microsoft Windows NT 6.1") > -1){
         myNewObj["64-bit Microsoft Windows 7"] += myObj[key];
    } else if (key.indexOf("Microsoft Windows NT 6.2") > -1){
         myNewObj["64-bit Microsoft Windows 8"] += myObj[key];
    } else {
         myNewObj[key] = myObj[key];
    }
}
```

Something like that should work, I haven't tested it but it seems right in my head :)

Here's a JS Fiddle, it should work right:
https://jsfiddle.net/n3wp70me/

Comment: Don't forget to `var key;`

Comment: Yes, But I'm wondering whether I could it robust. In case I want to support XP, or windows 10 then it would become a lot of if()else() right?

Comment: Or a switch statement, but you just need to check for each string condition and add it to the right property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach.  Once again using regex values.
It should be said though that what you're asking to do will result in a loss of information.  Javascript objects must have unique keys, so if you collapse what used to be 2 distinct keys into one, then their values will overwrite each other.

for example:
original keys
64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700
and
64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200
Will both become
64-bit Microsoft Windows 7

So you'll end up losing the value 3, it will be overwritten to the value 4.

```
var dict = {"64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200":1,"32-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9137":2,"64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.3700":3,"64-bit Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.1200":4};

var w7 = /Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.*/;
var w8 = /Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.*/;

var i, len, outKey, key, keys = Object.keys(dict), out = {};
for (i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    key = keys[i];
    outKey = key.replace(w7, 'Microsoft Windows 7');
    outKey = outKey.replace(w8, 'Microsoft Windows 8');
    out[outKey] = dict[key];
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: the replace is also good. But I think we could create a dictionary and iterate through the dictionary to do the replace